# Sharp preview thumbnails on Desktop

Tags: icons

Since one can change the symbol size, e.g. for a preview thumbnail of a photo file on desktop, the preview looks very unsharp and unattractive. Is there a way to modify this? E.g. let the thumbnail generator spend more time on creating those preview icon symbols?

Thanks

Comment: You can try defining your own thumbnailer for jpg images in gconf-editor. These links provide some hints how to go about it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=536874, http://superuser.com/questions/249646/fastest-jpeg-thumbnail-generator-for-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sharp icons are [vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics). You would need to replace any fuzzy or low-resolution icons with [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)s to have them be sharp in bigger resolutions. You can customize any icon by right clicking and choosing 'Properties'. Then click on the current icon in the window to bring up a file browser to pick a replacement.

To make your own replacements, or to convert low-resolution current icons, you would need a graphics program like GIMP or [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to make SVGs.

For photos, you would need to manually create an SVG of each one individually to have sharp thumbnails at bigger sizes.

Try resizing a few of the default icons on your desktop. Some are really sharp at any resolution, some are not. The sharp ones are vector graphics.

Comment: Nope, my photos I have on Desktop are sharp as hell. Also, I won't replace the thumbnail by SVG, mainly because of very poor results. High resolution thumbnails would help here, since scaling here produces the fuzziness. I think I will edit my question and replace icon with thumbnail, I think then people get my original intend.

Comment: It looks like Phatch can batch produce thumbnails in larger resolutions, with optional drop shadow & other effects too. The trick would be to have Nautilus use your new thumbnails on the desktop. Maybe run a batch and then move them to the default icons folder? Phatch info here: http://photobatch.wikidot.com/getting-started  Good question though, I'd like to see this feature.